# Is it possible to load a specific div from a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, load, selector

Does anyone know if it's possible to load a specific div from a variable like

```
$item = '#help_mobiel_prive';

$('#infopopup_content').load('help.html'+ $item, function() {
```

only that one doesn't work

Comment: the div selector like #somediv

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that what you mean to do is something like this:

```
var $item = '#myDiv';
$("#infopopup_content").load('help.html ' + $item, function() {
    //blah blah
);
```

Make sure there's a space between the file you're trying to load, and the selector. So instead of:

```
load('help.html' + $item...
```

Use:

```
load('help.html ' + $item...
```

So the concatenated string would be `'help.html #myDiv'`.

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load):

> In jQuery 1.2 you can now specify a
>   jQuery selector in the URL. Doing so
>   will filter the incoming HTML
>   document, only injecting the elements
>   that match the selector. The syntax
>   looks something like "url #some >
>   selector". Default selector "body>*"
>   always applies. If the URL contains a
>   space it should be escape()d. See the
>   examples for more information.

Comment: yes, but instead for #myDiv use a variable like $item
that would save me off putting the load function in every else if statement

Comment: As long as item contains a valid jQuery selector. I've edited the answer.

Comment: LOL, which is now almost the same as your question, so YES, the answer is YES :)

Comment: No Richard, like this: 'help.html '+$item; That will create a string like: 'help.html #myDiv' if the value of $item = '#myDiv' ($item has to be a string, it cannot be a jQuery object or array or whatever)

Comment: Karim,Pim thanks I put a space between the first quotes
I did not imediately catch(or see) what you where trying to say 
So it will come out as somefile[space]#somediv

Comment: Thanks Pim, I had to do some day job stuff. Richard, does that work now?